# Client /Server ipv6 with TSP

Tags: winapi, ipv6

My problem is to connect all my students while in an online classroom so each one has incoming access to each other to share their app, no matter if they are behind nat or firewall.

So far I have achieved this with VPN with the aid of my own [Turbo VPN](http://www.turboirc.com/tvpn).
However I would like to start using IPv6 to achieve my goal.

For students that already have IPv6, fine.
For students that do not have IPv6, I was thinking of sharing my own /48 with them, over TSP.

I was looking for the gogoClient or SixxS that do that, but I did not find example "server software".

I have seen aicuu and understood the authentication methods used, but as long as the session with the sixxs server is terminated I cannot understand what is going on, i.e. the udp transfer of the packets over the tsp.

Can you point me to some code doing all that server/client stuff?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"